# NetBeans warning when opening it that the JDK is missing

Tags: openjdk, netbeans

I have installed jdk version 1.8.0_131 in 16.04, but when I try to run NetBeans it is showing this error:

[image: check error image]

```
The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules  
Please use the --jdkhome command line option to specify a JDK  
installation or see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre for  
more information.
```

Additional information about the installation history of Java 9, which was installed alongside Java 8 and later removed, is in the comments.

What may cause this error and how could it be fixed?

Comment: Where is your jdk installed?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_131"  from the Ubuntu 16.04 repos is installed in `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: /usr/bin/java      its this

Comment: yah right @karel

Comment: Does the command `update-java-alternatives -l` show that you have more than one version of Java installed? If so `update-java-alternatives -set [name]` will change to *java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64* ... or maybe *java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386* in 32-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: It show's  "java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"  and
"java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64       1091       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64"

Comment: Java 9 from the Ubuntu repositories is a development release of Java which is not compatible with NetBeans, but Java 8 from the Ubuntu repositories which you have installed is compatible with NetBeans. Because Java 9 is a newer release it probably messed up your default Java path, at least that's what Java 9 did in my Ubuntu when I tried installing it.

Comment: Yeah I know that i'm using java 8

Comment: I removed java 9 if that was the case as u said but its still the same   @karel

Comment: That also happened to me. Removing Java 9 didn't change anything. I found an answer that worked for me at Stack Overflow Q&A, but  I didn't write it down and now I forgot what I did. If I can find the answer I used to fix the Java path, I'll post an answer to this question.

Comment: Okay, looking forward

Comment: It's  this `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games":/$JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" "` @karel

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the information that was added to the question via comments, you installed Java 9 which is not compatible with NetBeans and then removed it, but NetBeans still shows a warning message that JDK is missing, so you need to update $JAVA_HOME to point to Java 8.

1. Uninstall NetBeans.

   ```
   sudo apt purge netbeans
   ```
2. Open the terminal and open /etc/environment file for editing in nano text editor:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/environment
   ```
3. Append the following text string to the end of the line that starts with `PATH="` It's the first line in my `/etc/environment` file.

   ```
   :/$JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" "
   ```

   The two `"` characters at the end are for closing the `"` in `PATH="` and the other `"` after `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`. I used double quote characters in my `/etc/environment` file, I hope your `/etc/environment` uses double quote characters too.  You can see that in the `/etc/environment` file every individual path is separated by the string `:/`

   Also I don't have any `$JAVA_HOME` for `java-9` in my `/etc/environment` file, I only have `$JAVA_HOME` for `java-8`.
4. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited in nano to its current location.
5. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.
6. Logout and then login again in order that the changes in `/etc/environment` will take effect.
7. Reinstall NetBeans.

   ```
   sudo apt install netbeans
   ```

Comment: Didn't worked, still the same

Comment: Please open the `/etc/environment` file in gedit and read it carefully to make sure that you didn't make any typing errors when you were editing it. Here is an example line: `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/$JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" "`. Your line may have some additional paths that this example line doesn't have, that's OK as long as the form of the line is correct.

Comment: No its exactly the same  `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games":/$JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" "`

Comment: Hey I reinstalled it and now its working , I had `NetBeans 8.2` and now I installed `NetBeans 8.1` I guess 8.2 had some problem thank you so much@karel